# How to bypass "Repeat / Use Photo" preview view while taking photo using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there any way to bypass "Repeat / Use Photo" preview view while taking photo using `UIImagePickerController`?

I tried setting the `allowsEditing` to `NO`, but no progress.

I made a custom `CameraOverlayView` then the above mention problem was solved but having a new problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794594/how-to-prevent-an-extra-black-border-added-by-the-custom-cameraoverlayview-pin).

The App requires just with a tap on **TakePicture** then the image must be delivered to a handler. The aim is to avoid extra tap on **Use Photo**.

An answer to either of a problem would be appreciated.

[image]